# Эскпорт базы в excel

Tags: servlet, java-ee, excel, jsp, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток! Мне нужна помощь, в общем, дело такое. Мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы все данные из базы данных выводились в эксель. Так я подключаюсь к базе:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

         OutputStream out = null;

     PrintWriter out2 = response.getWriter();
        Connection con = null;
        Statement sql = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List dataList5 = new ArrayList();
           try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", "root", "123456789");
    sql = con.createStatement();
    }catch(Exception e){

        out2.print("ERROR IN CONNECTION" + e);
    }

            String query = "select * from user";

            try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
                s.executeQuery(query);
                rs = s.getResultSet();
                 while (rs.next()) {
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("name"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("surname"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("lastname"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("post"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("job"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("mobile"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("home"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("tel"));
                    dataList5.add(rs.getString("email"));
                    }
                for(int i=0;i<dataList5.size();i++){
                dataList5.get(i);
                }
                rs.close();

             }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);
        }
```

Затем эти данные пытаюсь экспортировать в эксель:

```
 try
    {

     response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=sampleName.xls");

     WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
     WritableSheet s = w.createSheet("Demo", 0);

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
     s.addCell(new Label(i, j, dataList5.get(0).toString()));
}
}
     w.write();
     w.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
     throw new ServletException("Exception in Excel Sample Servlet", e);
    } finally
    {
     if (out != null)
      out.close();
    }
    }
```

Я для примера хочу вывести сначала первую строку, но что-то у меня не выходит. В хроме когда нажимаю, выходит веб-страница недоступна. А если делаю без подключения к базе, а просто какое-нибудь слово, то это срабатывает и экспортирует в эксель. А как только добавляю базу к сервлету, вот такая вот хреновина. Помогите, может, я делаю что-то неправильно? Экспорт с помощью jxl делался.

Проблема не в подключений к базе, отдельно к базе подключается, а вместе не работает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без подключения к базе работает, а с подключением нет, то, очевидно, проблема в подключении. Это может быть либо невозможность подключиться к базе данных (из-за неверно уrазанного адреса базы или отсутствия класса драйвера MySQL), либо ошибка при выполнении запроса, либо ошибка при обработке результатов запроса. В любом случае, смотрите в лог сервера, скорее всего ошибка отобразится там. И не стесняйтесь пользоваться отладчиком Просто пройдите вашу программу пошагово и посмотрите, все ли шаги выполняются так, как вы ожидаете.

И ещё: давайте переменным более адекватные имена. Называть переменные `out2` или `dataList5` - плохая практика, это затрудняет понимание кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но дело в том что когда делаю по отдельности все работает, то есть либо подключается к базе и берет данные, либо экспортирует в эксель, но все вместе не выходит:(

И еще: спасибо за совет, в будущем постараюсь сделать все понятнее:)

Comment: @lp_4eva, вы уверены? Пройдитесь по объединённой программе отладчиком и выясните, где конкретно происходит ошибка. Ещё мне не нравится, как вы записываете данные в таблицу:

    s.addCell(new Label(i, j, dataList5.get(0).toString()));

Вы в каждую ячейку записываете один и тот же элемент. И ещё, вы очень странно обрабатываете результат, пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите, _что_ вы добавляете в список.

Comment: А я знаю, что я добавляю один и тот же элемент, это так для проверки, когда добавлю один, добавлю и другие. В общем, я делаю отладку и кое-что изменила, после этого у меня эксель файл экспортируется, только он пустой. А изменила я вот это `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` и это  `response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");`, у меня получалось так, что в одном сервлете 2 респонса с разными типами, я оставила только "application/vnd.ms-excel". После этого появилась возможность экспортировать, но там нет моих данных, что плохо. :( Там вообще пусто.

Comment: Ой, все решилось:))) Дело оказалось в response, при второй попытке отладки обнаружилось :) Спасибо, что пытались помочь)